# public List<string> filled in one function becomes empty outside the function

Tags: c#, list, windows-10

I have class A in one file

```
public class A
{
    public List<string> details; 

    public void fillList()
    {
        details = new List<string>();
        details.Add("abc");
        details.Add("xyz");}
    }
    public string[] convertToArray()
    {
    File.AppendAllText(path,"print list content \n");  /* this is getting printed */
    File.AppendAllLines(path, details.ToArray());  /* no contents are getting printed here */
    return details.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I'm not able to access this list content outside this function.outside this function list is becoming empty.

I tried using static keyword as well.

Please suggest me solution to access this list outside.

I'm facing this issue only in windows 10.

This is happening for all types not only for List.

Comment: You have not initialised the list. Try: `List<string> details=new List<string>();`

Comment: It's impossible for the list to become empty unless you clear it. I'd also recommend adding the initialization to the fill list method (I'm assuming you're initializing it elsewhere, since you would get a `NullReferenceException` upon calling `fillList()` otherwise). Also note that `empty` and `null` are different things. If you mean `null`, please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I'm initializing it in fillList function, hence I'm not getting NullReferenceException. I tried it initializing outside function as well i.e public List<string> details = new List<string>();  This issue I'm facing only in windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? If so can you show us the code where you expect it not to be empty?

Comment: yes I tried debugging code. when I trying to access this variable in other function of same class, list becomes empty.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you show us the code where you: 1. initialize an object of Type `A`.  - 2. Call it's `fillList()` function. - 3. Expect the object's list not be empty.

Comment: public class A
{
    public List<string> details; 

    public void fillList()
    {
        details = new List<string>();
        details.Add("abc");
        details.Add("xyz");}
    }
}

Comment: Where do you: `var myA = new A();` ? Where do you `myA.fillList();`? Where is `myA.details` empty?. Please edit your question to show us where you do this :-)

Comment: Here is a [Fiddle with your code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1ZFYrV). Now tell me where the exact issue is? Because this code is running just fine :-)

Comment: This is my complete code :

Comment: // ChildClass.cs : class A
  // MainClass.cs : class Program

    public class A
    {
        public List<string> details; 

        public void fillList()
        {
            details = new List<string>();
            details.Add("abc");
            details.Add("xyz");}
        }
        public string[] convertToArray()
     {
  File.AppendAllText(path,"print list content \n");  /* this is getting printed */
  File.AppendAllLines(path, details.ToArray());  /* no contents are getting printed here */
  return details.ToArray();
     }
    }

Comment: /* MainClass.cs */

public class Program
{
public string[] array = new string[1000];

public void startUp()
{
A obj = new A();
obj.fillList();
array = obj.convertToArray();
}

}

Comment: Well you don't have a the `Public void Main()` method (If it is a console program you are doing). [Here is your code working](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jU8209)

Answer (score 2):

try this - new up the list in the constructor to avoid a null ref exception:

```
public class A
{
    public List<string> details; 

   public A()
   {
        details = new List<string>();
   }

    public void fillList()
    {
        details.Add("abc");
        details.Add("xyz");}
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this fix a potential `NullReferenceException`. However the problem is not `details` being null.